# Remove custom object in array

Tags: swift2

I have custom objects (Scan) in an array. I would like to remove a specific object, it's not working. Here is my code :

```
class Scan : NSObject, NSCoding {

    let code : String
    let title : String
    let scanDate : NSDate

    init(code: String, title: String, scanDate: NSDate) {
        self.code = code
        self.title = title
        self.scanDate = scanDate
    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let code = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("code") as? String,
            let title = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as? String,
            let scanDate = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("scanDate") as? NSDate
            else { return nil }

        self.init(code: code, title: title, scanDate: scanDate)
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
        coder.encodeObject(self.code, forKey: "code")
        coder.encodeObject(self.scanDate, forKey: "scanDate")
    }
}

func == (lhs: Scan, rhs: Scan) -> Bool {
    return lhs.code == rhs.code
}
```

And in an other class :

```
func saveScan(scan: Scan){
        var allScans = scans()
        allScans.append(scan)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(allScans, toFile: filePath)

    }

    func deleteScan(scan: Scan) {
        var archivedScans = scans()
        archivedScans.removeObject(scan)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(archivedScans, toFile: filePath)
    }

    func scans() -> [Scan] {
        let scans =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as? [Scan] ?? [Scan]()
        return scans
    }
```

Array extension :

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    mutating func removeObject(object : Generator.Element) {
        if let index = self.indexOf(object) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

`archivedScans.removeObject(scan)` is not working (archivedScans has the same elements before and after the removeObject).
Do yo see why the delete is not working ?

Comment: What "is not working?"  Are you seeing an error?

Comment: The array has the same elements before and after the removeObject()

Comment: What happens if you change `Generator.Element` to just `Element` in your Array extension?  Additionally, are you sure `scan` is in your array before you try to remove it?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Yes i am sur that the object is in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality is not implemented correctly because the `Scan` class is a subclass of `NSObject`. We should override the `isEqual` and `hash` methods

Correct code :

```
import Foundation

class Scan : NSObject, NSCoding {

    let code : String
    let title : String
    let scanDate : NSDate

    init(code: String, title: String, scanDate: NSDate) {
        self.code = code
        self.title = title
        self.scanDate = scanDate
    }

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let code = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("code") as? String,
            let title = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as? String,
            let scanDate = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("scanDate") as? NSDate
            else { return nil }

        self.init(code: code, title: title, scanDate: scanDate)
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(self.title, forKey: "title")
        coder.encodeObject(self.code, forKey: "code")
        coder.encodeObject(self.scanDate, forKey: "scanDate")
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? Scan {
            return self.code == object.code
        }
        return false
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return self.code.hashValue
    }
}
```